# [TKinter]Create multiple buttons with same configure() atributes

Tags: python, tkinter

So,the problem is that I have dozens of buttons with same configuration and i want to shorten it so that I dont need to write same config to each button.

**Here is example of code:**

```
  self.Button1 = tk.Button(self.ButtonsFrame1)
  self.Button1.place(relx=0.664, rely=0.275, height=40, width=94)
  self.Button1.configure(activebackground="beige",
                              activeforeground="#000000",
                              background="#8c9eef",
                              compound='left',
                              foreground="#000000",
                              highlightbackground="#d9d9d9",
                              highlightcolor="black",
                              pady="0",
                              text='''button1''')

  self.Button2 = tk.Button(self.ButtonsFrame2)
  self.Button2.place(relx=0.824, rely=0.275, height=40, width=94)
  self.Button2.configure(activebackground="beige",
                                activeforeground="#000000",
                                background="#8c9eef",
                                compound='left',
                                foreground="#000000",
                                highlightbackground="#d9d9d9",
                                highlightcolor="black",
                                pady="0",
                                text='''button2''')
```

As you can see many elements of configure() are the same, and I know it can be shorter but I don't have any idea on how to do that. Can you help me?

Comment: You can store the options in a dictionary, like `options = {'activeforeground':"#000000",'background':"#8c9eef",'compound':'left',...}` and then `self.button2.configure(**options)` and so on for each needed buttons. This way you dont have to switch your widgets from `tk` to `ttk` either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `Style` and then apply it to your buttons.

Here's some examples from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style) using [Tk themed widgets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html):

```
from tkinter import ttk
# change default style for every button 
ttk.Style().configure("TButton", padding=6, relief="flat", background="#ccc")
btn = ttk.Button(text="Sample")
```

Second example:

```
# override the basic Tk widgets
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

style = Style()
style.configure("my.TButton", activebackground="beige",
                              activeforeground="#000000",
                              background="#8c9eef",
                              compound='left',
                              foreground="#000000",
                              highlightbackground="#d9d9d9",
                              highlightcolor="black",
                              pady="0")
btn1 = Button(style="my.TButton", text="button1")
btn2 = Button(style="my.TButton", text="button2")
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much, that was exacly what i was looking for

Comment: Would styles also work with non `ttk` widgets? like OP's code?

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria I edited my answer to show ho to override the classic Tk widgets

Comment: You are still using the `ttk` widgets but under the _disguise_ of `tk`...? What does it fix? It is still a `ttk` widget and not a `tk` one

Comment: Yes, that's suggested in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#using-ttk) --of course one should know what one's doing.